# How to inject a singleton using hilt inside a composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to inject a singleton class that was defined in a hiltmodule inside a composable.
I know how to inject viewmodels but what about singleton classes ?

```
@Inject
    lateinit var mysingleton: MySingletonClass
```

This code works fine in an activity but carrying it around from the activity to the composable that uses it is a long way ...
Any better solution ?

Answer (score 23):

You should not inject dependencies into a function, which is what a [@Composable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Composable) is. You may want to inject them into the ViewModel or the Activity.

If you need access to a ViewModel-scoped (or Application-scoped) singleton inside a @Composable, you can have that singleton injected into the ViewModel, and then access the ViewModel from the @Composable.

You can inject that singleton into the ViewModel by annotating the provider function for that object in the ViewModel hilt module as @ViewScoped.

You could install the provider into the SingletonComponent::class and annotate it as @Singleton, if you want a singleton for the whole app, instead of a singleton per ViewModel instance. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-scopes).

**Hilt module file**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object ViewModelModule {

    @ViewScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideMySingleton(): MySingletonClass = MySingletonClass()
}
```

**Your ViewModel class:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel
@Inject constructor(
    val mySingleton: MySingletonClass
): ViewModel() {

...

}
```

**Your @Composable function:**

```
@Composable fun DisplayPrettyScreen() {
...
    val viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val singleton = viewModel.mySingleton  //no need to assign it to a local variable, just for explanation purposes

}
```

Comment: You can technically do that, but viewmodels are intended to be state holders, not dependency holders!

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. How is this ViewModel being a "dependency holder"?

Comment: Your UI dependencies should be injected in your UI layer. Injecting them in a ViewModel would mean you're making it dependant on something that does not correlate to its responsibility, which is holding your UI state and its logic.

Comment: And where do you see that a UI dependency has been injected into the ViewModel here? We are just injecting something in the viewmodel, but it doesnt say anywhere that it is a "UI dependency" . Most likely, the person who asked the question was writing code into the activity when the logic should have really been in the ViewModel. If you find yourself injecting things in the UI, you want to rethink if it really belongs in the UI (inject it in the Activity and pass it as parameter to the @Composables) or should be injected in a different layer, most likely VierwModel.

Comment: I do agree with what you have said, in fact that's how I do my injections. Of course you want to inject your domain/data depenedncies in your ViewModels, I just disagrees with the idea of injecting an actual UI dependency in a viewmodel (my assumption of the dependency being "UI" is becuse he's trying to inject in a composable directly) just to access it from outside (from a composable for instance) and nothing else. I think the correct way to do it is as you said, injecting in the activity, and passing it to the composables.

Answer (score 10):

I also thought that is not possible but then found way... tried it and seems it works.

define you entry point interface:

```
private lateinit var dataStoreEntryPoint: DataStoreEntryPoint

@Composable
fun requireDataStoreEntryPoint(): DataStoreEntryPoint {
    if (!::dataStoreEntryPoint.isInitialized) {
        dataStoreEntryPoint =
            EntryPoints.get(
                LocalContext.current.applicationContext,
                DataStoreEntryPoint::class.java,
            )
    }
    return dataStoreEntryPoint
}

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface DataStoreEntryPoint {
    val dataStoreRepo: DataStoreRepo
}
```

DataStoreRepo is singleton defined in Hilt

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDataStoreRepository(dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>): DataStoreRepo =
        DataStoreRepo(dataStore)
```

and then use in composable:

```
@Composable
fun ComposableFuncionName(dataStoreRepo: DataStoreRepo = requireDataStoreEntryPoint().dataStoreRepo){
...
}
```

Comment: if you are using MVVM, you don't use repos directly in the UI. That's what the viewmodel is for. There's a lot of documentation on App Architecture out there -which this post does not follow in a few different ways.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @DissidentDev The question is about injecting Singleton. There can be other dependencies (not repository) that are required in the composable but have nothing to do with business logic and isn't part of the architecture.

Comment: @Saurabh How can a correct answer have a repository injected in the UI? Please read a bit about Android architecture before commenting/posting.

Comment: Yes, its example of principle, not consider to using DataStoreRepo in composable directly as great idea.... if you use MVVM.... only use it to prove possibility of injection

Comment: This is the correct answer that doesn't mix architecture layers

Comment: Maybe instead of global lateinit var we could use compose remember?
```@Composable
fun rememberDataStoreRepo(): DataStoreRepo {
    val applicationContext = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
    return remember(applicationContext) {
        EntryPoints.get(applicationContext, DataStoreEntryPoint::class.java). dataStoreRepo
    }
}```

Answer (score -4):

You can inject it inside your composable like this:

```
val myViewModel = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel>()
```