# How to inject other objects in Composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have an object in my Hilt dependency which I want to inject into a Composable function.

```
@Composable
fun ABCScreen(
    viewModel: ABCViewModel = viewModel(),
    router: Router       <--- Want to inject this like viewmodel
) { .... }
```

Router defined in ActivityComponent

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
class ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideRouter(activity: FragmentActivity): Router =
        AppFragmentRouter(R.id.container, activity)
```

I want to inject router as well in composable. It is already defined in ActivityComponent scope and I am injecting it in other places and it works fine. If I manually pass the router fetching from the activity that is also working fine which I don't want.

I want to inject router in my composable function directly. any idea on how to do this? Like hot o create a function like hiltViewModel() which gives a router object and can be used in a function parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inject a singleton using hilt inside a composable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457125/how-to-inject-a-singleton-using-hilt-inside-a-composable)

Comment: No. I can not use ViewModel as the hilt dependency has the scope of ActivityComponent and since ViewModel is higher in the hierarchy it cannot be injected hence I am trying to inject it in the Composable instead of ViewModel.

Comment: Did you check the answers? Specifically this one -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73007239/4809922