Composable throws "kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Unknown file" compile error
I wish to have an interface which has a composable function Show like this in Android project feature module A.
interface AInterface {
    @Composable
    fun Show(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)
}

class AInterfaceImpl : AInterface {
    @Composable
    override fun Show(modifier: Modifier) {
        Text(
            modifier = modifier,
            text = "Message",
        )
    }
}

And inject the AInterfaceImpl object to Android project feature module B using Hilt and when I call aInterfaceImpl.Show(modifier) in Composable function from module B, it throws the below compile error.
@Composable
fun ShowAInterfaceImpl(
    modifier: Modifier,
    aInterface: AInterface
) {
    aInterface.Show(
        modifier = modifier
    )

}

kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Unknown file
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.IrUtilsKt.getFile(IrUtils.kt:634)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.InferenceFunctionDeclaration.toScheme(ComposableTargetAnnotationsTransformer.kt:680)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.InferenceFunctionDeclaration.toDeclaredScheme(ComposableTargetAnnotationsTransformer.kt:671)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.InferenceFunction.toDeclaredScheme$default(ComposableTargetAnnotationsTransformer.kt:614)

I spent a lot of time working around it, however, I have not got any clue.
If anyone has any clue, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457125/how-to-inject-a-singleton-using-hilt-inside-a-composable

I have investigated this issue for a long time and found the below two issues:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317490247
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165812010

So basically, Composable function in the interface does not support the function parameter default value.
interface AInterface {
    @Composable
    fun Show(modifier: Modifier)
}

So it works. Thanks.
